# Secure LDAP login CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am currently using LDAP as a logon solution in cakephp and the plugin queencitycodefactory. I was wondering if there is any way to get the Secure LDAP? Do i need to use another plugin like ZoomRx or are there any other easier solution?

Comment: Looking through the plugin code it appears to just be a wrapper for [ldap_connect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php). You should be able to (theoretically) set the host parameter to the format `ldaps://hostname:port` and port parameter to null. Otherwise you may need to make a slight modification to the plugin to get it to work.

Comment: I will make some modifications and see if i can get it working. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hmm it does not seem to work. It is unable to bind the connection :S